# MySQL Upgrade 5.x upgrade

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL Server version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2. 
I tried to update the version to 5.5.35 using the following command and the output also is shown below

```
root@MATRiXDev:/home/rpolepeddi# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 215 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main mysql-server all 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [11.2 kB]
Fetched 11.2 kB in 0s (73.1 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 62346 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql-server 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (using .../mysql-server_5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql-server ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
```

But after I launch MySQL it still shows that is 5.5.28 instead of 5.5.35. Can someone explain this ?

```
root@MATRiXDev:/etc/mysql# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 294
Server version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Have you `service mysql restart` ?

Comment: I restarted the service and also tried rebooting the system.

Comment: What's the version listed on `dpkg -l | grep -i mysql`? Try remove and install again?

Comment: Do you mean removing the existing installation and reinstall ? I'm aware of that approach but I need to understand what the output in my question means and why is not working?